# RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin al ejecutar .exe

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

Me encuentro realizando un proyecto, en python.
Acabo de hacer varias lineas y he utilizado pyintsaller para crear el ejecutable. Se crea todo bien el archivo, voy a la carpeta dist y al ejecutar el .exe me figura el siguiente error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Programa_Principal.py", line 183, in <module>
>   File "Programa_Principal.py", line 138, in obtener_opcion
> RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
> ```

¿Alguna solución? Ya que de por si me cuesta la programación, ver estos errores que no le encuentro solución ni se a que se deben, me complican aun mas!

### Edición

Este es el código:

```
def mostrar_opciones():
    print("""
Opciones:
1. Registrar Cliente
2. Buscar Cliente
3. Crear Reserva
4. Mostrar la actividad del día
5. Salir
""")

def obtener_opcion():
    mostrar_opciones()
    seleccion = input()
    return input("Selecciona una opción: ")
```

Genero el exe  con:

```
pyinstaller --clean --onefile --windowed Programa_Principal.py
```

Por lo que entiendo, `input()` no se puede usar en .exe El tema es que, ¿como puedo reemplazar `input()`? Existe alguna forma? Porque tengo en mi código varios `input`, y no quisiera modificar todos a esta altura del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Estas usando la opcion `-w`, `--windowed` o `--noconsole` al generar el ejecutable? Si es asi, el error se debe a que en este caso no se proporciona una instancia de la consola para i/o estándar por lo que input no funcionara. Si se trata de una CLI no uses esa opción, si es una GUI no uses `input()`

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta!
Estoy usando esta opcion
pyinstaller --clean --onefile --windowed Programa_Principal.py

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas creando el ejecutable con la opción  `--windowed`, si nos vamos a [la documentación](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=windowed#cmdoption-w) (traducida libremente al español):

> `-w, --windowed, --noconsole`
>
> En Windows y Mac OS X: no se proporcionan una ventana de consola para la entrada/salida
> estándar. En Mac OS esto también activa la generación de un paquete .app para Mac OS. En Windows esta opción se activa automáticamente si el
> script principal es un archivo '.pyw'. Esta opción se ignora en sistemas
> *NIX.

Esta opción esta pensada para cuando nuestra aplicación es una GUI (interfaz gráfica), como es cualquier app creada con framework gráficos como Tkinter, Gtk, Qt, etc. En estos casos solemos querer que se abra nuestra interfaz gráfica sin abrir una instancia de la consola también, y es esto justamente lo que hace esta opción.

En tu caso estas creando una interfaz de linea de comandos (por lo que muestras en tu código) que hace uso de la entrada estándar mediante `input`  y de la salida estándar con `print` y que por tanto debe ejecutarse en la consola. Si usas
`--windowed` a la vez que `input` este fallara al intentar leer desde *stdin*.

En definitiva, no uses la opcional `--windowed` al generar el ejecutable (ni llames a tu script `lo_que_sea.pyw` en Windows). En tu caso simplemente:

```
pyinstaller --clean --onefile Programa_Principal.py
```

debería resolver este problema.

Comment: Gracias! Ahora entiendo! Tengo que tener en cuenta eso, no lo sabía! Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Ahi probé y funcionó!